# TypeError: Cannot read property 'capture' of undefined at ChildScope.$scope.exportReport

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, amcharts, pdfmake

I am using pdfMake to export some html content and amCharts graphs to pdf.
I used this amCharts [demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/35076c4d7b6eef7764dacc61f72adadc) which is perfect to me it presents the code I need.
Well I copied exactly the code, I only added $scope to the function
and now I have

```
$scope.exportReport = function() {
  //the same code existing in the codepen.io   
}
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'capture' of undefined
at ChildScope.$scope.exportReport (reporting.controller.js:416)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15126), <anonymous>:4:227)
at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:16213)
at callback (angular.js:26592)
at ChildScope.$eval (angular.js:17994)
at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:18094)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:26597)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

so the code won't work because chart["export"] is undefined and I don't know why!

```
 chart["export"].capture({}, function() {
                    this.toJPG({}, function(data) {

                        // Save chart data into chart object itself
                        this.setup.chart.exportedImage = data;

                        // Reduce the remaining counter
                        charts_remaining--;

                        // Check if we got all of the charts
                        if (charts_remaining == 0) {
                            // Yup, we got all of them
                            // Let's proceed to putting PDF together
                            generatePDF();
                        }

                    });
                });
```

I installed all the necessary libraries and files!
My code :

```
$scope.exportReport = function() {

        // So that we know export was started
        console.log("Starting export...");

        // Define IDs of the charts we want to include in the report
        var ids = ["chartdiv1", "chartdiv2"];

        // Collect actual chart objects out of the AmCharts.charts array
        var charts = {},
            charts_remaining = ids.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < AmCharts.charts.length; x++) {
                if (AmCharts.charts[x].div.id == ids[i])
                    charts[ids[i]] = AmCharts.charts[x];
            }
        }

        // Trigger export of each chart
        for (var x in charts) {
            if (charts.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                var chart = charts[x];
                chart["export"].capture({}, function() {
                    this.toJPG({}, function(data) {

                        // Save chart data into chart object itself
                        this.setup.chart.exportedImage = data;

                        // Reduce the remaining counter
                        charts_remaining--;

                        // Check if we got all of the charts
                        if (charts_remaining == 0) {
                            // Yup, we got all of them
                            // Let's proceed to putting PDF together
                            generatePDF();
                        }

                    });
                });
            }
        }

        function generatePDF() {

            // Log
            console.log("Generating PDF...");

            // Initiliaze a PDF layout
            var layout = {
                "content": [],
                "styles": {
                    "header": {
                        "fontSize": 18,
                        "bold": true,
                        "background": 'pink'
                    }
                }
            };

            layout.content.push({
                "columns": [{
                    "width": "33.33%",
                    "image": document.getElementById("logo").innerHTML,
                    "fit": [250, 300]
                }, {
                    "width": "*",
                    "image": charts["chartdiv1"].exportedImage,
                    "fit": [250, 300]
                }],
                "columnGap": 10
            });


            // Trigger the generation and download of the PDF
            // We will use the first chart as a base to execute Export on
            chart["export"].toPDF(layout, function (data) {
                this.download(data, "application/pdf", "reporting.pdf");
            });
        }}
```

Comment: could you provide pen\fiddle\plunkerof your code ?

Comment: @anoop I edited the question :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I had to add

```
        "export": {
            "enabled": true
        }
```

to all my charts!